# memcopying structure to another but getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++

When trying to copy two structures having character arrays, I'm getting a segmentation fault. Any pointers on this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    char name[8];
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    cout<< "hello\n";
            
    struct A obj;
    strcpy(obj.name, "hari");
    obj.age =5;
    struct A *b  =(struct A*)malloc(sizeof(struct A));
    memcpy(&b,&obj,sizeof(struct A));
    cout << b->name;
    cout<<b->age;
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to copy a structure to another, I'm getting segmentation fault on `memcpy()`.

Comment: An immediate source of SIGV is that: `memcpy(&b,&obj,sizeof``(struct A));` should be `memcpy(b,&obj,sizeof``(struct A));`, as in it's current form it is trying to copy the data into address of `b` pointer (rather than memory pointed to by `b`). There are multiple other issues with the code, though.

Comment: Prefer not to use pointers.  Use references instead.   Don't call `malloc` because `malloc` doesn't call constructors.

Comment: Prefer not to use `memcpy`.  Implement copy constructors and move constructors.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this (reference vs pointers) is wrong as a general advise, and wholly inappropriate in OP's code. Your point about `memcpy` is applicable in some cases, but not in others, and as a general advise, is not great either.

Comment: @SergeyA There is no need, in the OP's code, for dynamic memory allocation.  The variables can be declared locally and usage of `operator=`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews with that I agree, but it doesn't mean OP should use references!

Comment: There's no need to use `memcpy` here. Structs can be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```cpp
memcpy(&b,&obj,sizeof``(struct A));
```

is wrong. The variable `b` is a pointer and its size may be less than one of the structure. Also writing data of the structure to the poitner variable may set the pointer to an invalid value, making chance to cause Segmentation Fault.

You should write the data of the structure not to the pointer variable but the buffer that the pointer variable points at like this:

```cpp
memcpy(b,&obj,sizeof(struct A));
```

Comment: I think, the answer is to hypothetical where it could be firm. Size of the pointer is certainly smaller than the size of `A` (there are no physical systems where pointers are longer than 8 bytes). "May set the pointer" is also like Alice in Wonderland's " certain to disagree with one, sooner or later." - obviously, it **will** set the pointer to invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are copying the bytes to the wrong target address.

In this statement:

```cpp
memcpy(&b,&obj,sizeof(struct A));
```

`b` is an `A*` pointer to an `A` object that is allocated elsewhere in memory.  Rather than copying the bytes of `obj` into the allocated memory that `b` is pointing at, you are writing the bytes to the memory where `b` itself is located. Thus corrupting `b` (and surrounding memory), which leads to the segfault when you try to dereference `b` afterwards.

Simply remove the `&` operator from `b`, so that you will then be copying the bytes to the memory of the `A` object which `b` is pointing at, rather than to the memory where `b` itself is located:

```cpp
memcpy(b, &obj, sizeof(struct A));
```

That being said, all of this code is very much C, not C++ at all.  The C++ way to handle this is to not use `malloc()` and `memcpy()` at all, but rather to use constructors and assignment operators instead. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

struct A
{
    char name[8]; // better to use std::string instead, but
                  // since the question is about arrays, I'll
                  // leave this as-is...
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello\n";
            
    A obj;
    std::strcpy(obj.name, "hari");
    obj.age = 5;

    auto b = std::make_unique<A>(obj);
    // or, prior to C++14:
    // std::unique_ptr<A> b(new A(obj));

    /* or:
    auto b = std::make_unique<A>(); // or: std::unique_ptr<A> b(new A); 
    *b = obj;
    */

    std::cout << b->name;
    std::cout << b->age;

    return 0;
}
```